# Parametric equation of an ellipsoid

Tags: analysis, euclidean-geometry, parametric

Given the implicit expression of an ellipsoid $$\mathcal{E} : \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$ finding the parameterization $$\begin{cases}x=a\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\y=b\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\z=c\sin(\phi)\end{cases}$$ on the internet is quite easy, but what is the procedure to find a parameterization of any quadric (hyperbolic/elliptic hyperboloid/paraboloid)?

Comment: By in general, do you mean one not aligned to the x, y, and z axes?

Comment: @Laff70 I mean "any quadric". I edited the question.

Comment: There are "standard" parametrizations for axis-oriented quadrics using circular and/or hyperbolic functions, and these can be rotated or translated to handle general smooth quadrics. There are also rational parametrizations, the simplest non-trivial example being stereographic projection$$(u,v)\mapsto\frac{(2u,2v,u^2+v^2-1)}{u^2+v^2+1}$$for the unit sphere. Are there particular criteria you're seeking?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm seeking a "proof" of the standard parametrization.

Comment: It's given by "scaled spherical coordinates". In other words, if we cross out the coefficients on the right, we have a longitude ($\theta$)-latitude ($\phi$) parametrization of the unit sphere.